# Using LDAP with Karaf - Error

Tags: ldap, apache-karaf, ldap-query

i have some Problems using LDAP with Karaf.

```
    <jaas:config name="karaf" rank="2">
  <jaas:module className="org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.ldap.LDAPLoginModule" flags="required">
    initialContextFactory=com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory
    connection.username=uid=admin,ou=system
    connection.password=secret
    connection.url=ldap://localhost:10389
    user.base.dn=ou=user,dc=jobs,dc=com
    user.filter=(ou=%u)
    user.search.subtree=true
    role.base.dn=ou=groups,dc=jobs,dc=com
    role.name.attribute=cn
    role.filter=(member=cn=%nsdn)
    role.search.subtree=true
    authentication=simple
  </jaas:module>
```

is my jaas module for the ldap usage.

For testing i build a LDAP with the structure:

- Groups : in groups i add my roles
- in roles : i add my roles and with member of users
- users : my users i want to authenticate

The user is found by the ldap but not the role...

any idears=

[image: My Test LDAP Config]

Answer (score 1):

you need to add the role in karaf.admin (user.properties)config file.